# Create many public form in joomla

Tags: forms, components, joomla3.0

Do you know a free component for joomla? I need one which creates many pubblic forms and shows data in amministration area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use http://www.component-creator.com, it does exactly that: creates a whole MVC component that will work right out of the box.